# Importing file with UCS-2 Little Endian codification

Tags: import, text

I'm trying to import a text file with UCS-2 Little Endian codification but I can't read it correctly. There's any hidden option to read this files ??

I'd tried with `Import` (using `ByteOrdering` option) and `ReadList`.

And example file can be find [here](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/4156895/msscript.scp)

Thanks !!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect that you want the result of using `CharacterEncoding -> "Unicode"`:

```
Import["msscript.scp", "Text", CharacterEncoding -> "Unicode"]
```

and possibly also replacing the carriage return / newline pair with newline:

```
StringReplace[
 Import["msscript.scp", "Text", CharacterEncoding -> "Unicode"],
 "\r\n" -> "\n"
]
```

Comment: In fact, as I'm interested in the lines to analyze the content, for my works better this:

`StringReplace[#, "\r" -> ""] & /@ Import["msscript.scp", {"Text", "Lines"}, CharacterEncoding -> "Unicode"]; `

Comment: @SMiranda okay, I'm glad this helped.  For what it's worth `StringReplace` can operate on a list of strings so the output from this should be the same as what you wrote: `StringReplace[
 Import["msscript.scp", {"Text", "Lines"}, 
  CharacterEncoding -> "Unicode"],
 "\r" -> ""
 ]`